# Is it possible to make my files visible to all by a name when I haven't actually registered any domains

Tags: dns, server, port, hosting

I have applied for static IP for my pc to my ISP. I was just wondering that is their any way around of making my server online without any domain registration. I know my public ip will always be configurable through various ports on my apache. But will I be able to use my own domain names without registration just to cut out cost.

Answer (score 0):

Other machines will be able to find your machine from its static IP address.

If you don't register a domain for it, then other machines won't be able to use a domain name to look up the IP address. The domain name lookup is based on a public register - the actual architecture is distributed, but effectively it is a big list of domain name to IP addresses. Registration is the mechanism by which the mapping of the domain name to the IP address is allowed to be added to the public register. Once you have registered a domain name as belonging to you, your ISP or registration authority will be able to point that domain name to your static IP address.

So if you want to give your customers a domain name rather than an IP address, then you need to register the domain name.

If you only want to point a few machines to it and you have control of those machines, you can add the IP to the hosts file on those machines manually so it does not use the public domain name resolution system.

Comment: I actually want to host my public portfolio available to any customer. 

> Registration is the mechanism by the mapping of the domain name to
> the IP address becomes public.

You mean to say registration is a compulsory process to bind my public ip to a public domain name.

Comment: "Registration is the mechanism by the mapping of the domain name to the IP address becomes public."

You mean to say registration is a compulsory process to bind my public ip to a public domain name. I actually want to host my public portfolio available to any customer.

Comment: Yes, domain registration is a compulsory process to bind public IP address to a domain name. To host your portfolio, you can always add a website in IIS, having path to one of your directory or to C:\Inetpub, and access it via an IP address.

Comment: I am using Apache. In other 3rd party servers there are options such as CNAME etc but, I dont see such options in Apche, but only website/domain name. Is it that simple!!!


Moreover using simply IP for promotion would never make my site in google search and make me vulnerable as I may discontinue the IP sometime in future